# Automapper Failing when take latest from TFS

Tags: tfs, automapper

My team mate installed AutoMapper latest version in his workstation using 
    nuget in all the projects whereever referenced in the solution. In 
    package.config we can see the automapper latest version. It was building 
    properly in her machine. But when I take latest and run the project in my 
    machine, the Automapper failed but I can see in packages.config the new 
    version. But in reference the Automapper is showing not found with an yellow 
    icon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the NuGet Package didn't restored Automapper successfully.

Possible duplicate with this question:[TFS Can't Restore NuGet Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356229/tfs-cant-restore-nuget-package)

Try to make sure  both package sources are added to your **NuGet.config** file. Also ensure both sources are 'active'.

```
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org"
             value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <add key="example.com"
             value="http://example.com/feed/nuget/" />
    </packageSources>
    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All"
             value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```